# cmake project lib include dependencies

Tags: cmake

I have this :

```
project(my-group)

add_subdirectory(proj1)
add_subdirectory(proj2)
```

proj2 will need include files and .lib which will exist only after the generation of "proj1"

How can I do that except writing two cmakelists.txt (and compiling them one by one)

(I guess under VS it is called a "Solution")

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Assuming you have `proj1_lib` - library in the `proj1`, and `proj2_exe` - executable in the `proj2`, then correct linking would be `target_link_libraries(proj2_exe proj1_lib)`. This is explained in almost every tutorial.. Not sure what is a problem.